# CSS bottom doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a div representing a lesson that is dynamically "filled up" with a green span according to the student's percentage of completion of the lesson. So the height of the span is dynamically assigned. This works perfectly in all browsers except for Internet Explorer, where the span doesn't start from the bottom of the div, but it's half way in the middle,
as you can see from the pictures where the first lesson is 100% complete and the second is 25% complete:

Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera:

[image: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera]

Internet Explorer:

[image: Internet Explorer]

My HTML is:

```
  <div style="display:table; margin:0 auto;">

       <div class="detail_image">

            <div class="detail_image_cont">
                 <img src="images/thamatho/chapters/img.png" />  
            </div>
            <span style="height:<?php echo $completepercentage."%";?>">     
             </span>
      </div> 
 </div>
```

My CSS is:

```
 .detail_image{  
   display: table-cell;
   border: 4px solid #39C;
   width:48px;
   height:48px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align:center;
   -webkit-border-radius: 35px 35px 35px 35px; 
   -moz-border-radius:35px 35px 35px 35px;
   border-radius: 35px 35px 35px 35px;
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
   background-color:transparent;
 }


 .detail_image > span {
    width: 101%;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: -0.4px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #CFC; 
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 0%;
    z-index:1;
  }

 .detail_image_cont{ /* to center image in the div */
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
  }
```

Comment: Can you start a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Done: http://jsfiddle.net/Le7eo758/

Comment: What version of IE are you using? It looks the same to me in Chrome and IE9.

Comment: I'm using IE 11. In Chrome, it looks perfect, but not in IE11

Comment: I am not familiar with IE11. Does 11 still have compatibility mode? If so, maybe make sure it isn't enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block` to your span, it should help.

Comment: Thanks so much, but unfortunately it didn't help. The issue is still there even with display:block.